# printpreviewing data on access using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview

i am making a payroll system for my school proj. i had this form where you can print the data of the employee's info. such as name, taxes, deductions etc..

i searched for possible answers on the internet but all i had is this:

```
Dim ce = form1.grid.currentcell.Rowindex
e.Graphics.DrawString(Form1.dtg.Item(Form1.column.headertext, ce).value.tostring.systemfonts.brushes.black, 300, 200)
```

this code prints selected rows on the gridview(made manually using tools).
anyone know how can put my gridview access database selected row into printview form? thanks

Comment: Do you actually mean a `DataGridView` in a WinForms application?  Please be CLEAR.

Comment: yes the datagridview in winforms app.

Comment: If it's a `DataGridView` then please say that.  We shouldn't have to guess stuff like that.  It's not hard to use the actual names of things and it saves time and confusion.  Anyway, you need to use a `PrintDocument` and a `PrintPreviewDialog`, both of which can be added from the Toolbox.  Are you doing that?

Comment: yeah.. actually my problem is to print the selected row of the database in the print preview form